# JAVA заполнение двумерного массива

Tags: java

Данные приходят в виде массива, хочу перенести их в двумерный массив, для удобства. так. первый элемент массива - номер, элементы со 2 по 6 - параметры, 7 элемент - опять номер, а дальше параметры, для этого номера и так далее. делаю вот так , но получаю двумерный массив полностью заполненный последним номером и его параметрами, почему так?

```
int k;
for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {

    for (int i = 1; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][0] = result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][1] = result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][2] = result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 4; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][3] = result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 5; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][4] = result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i += 6) {
        cars[k][5] = result[i];
    }
}
```

Вот то, что сейчас получаю

```
 АЕ0000ІХ  5  ДА  нет  null  2001211001426 
 АЕ0000ІХ  5  ДА  нет  null  2001211001426 
 АЕ0000ІХ  5  ДА  нет  null  2001211001426 
 АЕ0000ІХ  5  ДА  нет  null  2001211001426 
 АЕ0000ІХ  5  ДА  нет  null  2001211001426
```

а данные которые обрабатываю, выглядят вот так:

`[2001211001426, АЕ0000ІХ, 5, ДА, нет, null, 2001211001433, АЕ0001ІТ, null, null, null, null, 2001211001440, АЕ0002ІТ, null, null, null, null, 2001211001457, АЕ0003КА, null, null, null, null, 2001211001464, АЕ0004ІХ, null, null, null, null]`

```
В первый столбец идут элементы с номер 1 +6 
во второй 2 +6 
в третий 3 +6
в четвертый 4 +6
в пятый 5 +6 
в шестой 0 +6
```

Comment: Честно ничего не понятно :) Приведите пожалуйста пример массива и матрицу, которую вы хотите получить.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что когда хотите например установить параметр `AE...` как первый элемент в строке, вы работаете все время с одной строчкой `k`. То есть вы проходитесь по всем `AE...` но устанавливаете лишь одной `k` строчке. Вот и получается, что вы устанавливаете каждой строчке матрицы значения лишь последнего номера.

Вот пример как можно реализовать, то что вам нужно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Исходный массив
    Object[] result = {"2001211001426", "АЕ0000ІХ", 5, "ДА", "нет", null, "2001211001433", "АЕ0001ІТ", null, null, null, null, "2001211001440", "АЕ0002ІТ", null, null, null, null, "2001211001457", "АЕ0003КА", null, null, null, null, "2001211001464", "АЕ0004ІХ", null, null, null, null};
    Object[][] cars = new Object[5][6];
    int l = 5;
    for(int k = 0; k < l; k++){
        //Индекс начала данных для k-того номера
        int i = k * 6;
        //Устанавливаем номер в конец строки
        cars[k][5] = result[i];
        //Потом все остальные параметры номера
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            cars[k][j] = result[i + j + 1];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            System.out.print(cars[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Я думаю код достаточно понятен. Его суть в том, что в отличие от вашего кода, где вы каждый каждый параметр номера устанавливаете построчно, мой код устанавливает сначала для одного номера все параметры, потом до другого и т.д.

Результат программы:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял суть)